# disable activity restarting on go back or forward

Tags: java, android, android-activity, restart

I have three activity in my application. In my second activity I have some elements that are made dynamically by user. When I click on device back button or go to third activity, second activity restarts. Why?
first activity:

```
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second );
 }
```

and in second activity i creat element:

```
       final  TableLayout tbl=(TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tblProduct);
   TableRow row=new TableRow(this);
   EditText ed=new EditText(this);
   ed.setLayoutParams( new TableRow.LayoutParams( 0, android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,.10f ) );
   row.addView(ed);
   tbl.addView(row);
```

when i back to first activity the created element be cleared.

Comment: don't call finish() on second activity while launching third activity. If you want to call finish() method then follow the below answer given by @adrian0110h.

Answer (score 0):

Since the elements are dynamically generated they are not stored anywhere
You can try storing element data in the `onPause()` method and restoring them in `onResume()` method